# convert csv data to json - csvhelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, csvhelper

My data in excel:

[image]

```
id  _npi_link_id    dtime   _dow    congestion_cost vkt _delay_time vol _type   anes    length  eed_lim v_speed
4706    3372355 1   2   0   2.08    0   11  Council Arterial    3   189 50  45.44
4708    3372355 1   2   0   0.38    0   2   Council Arterial    3   189 50  48
```

I am trying to parse id separate and rest of the data as json..I followed [this](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion/) example but I get empty feilds in Json.

[image]

My code:

**CSVHelper_Sample**

```
public class GeoFeatures
{
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public Json? Json { get; set; }
}

public class Json
{
    public string? GeoFeatures { get; set; }
}

public class FooMap : ClassMap<GeoFeatures>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.id);
        Map(m => m.Json).TypeConverter<JsonConverter<Json>>();
    }
}

public class JsonConverter<T> : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(text);
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
  IgnoreBlankLines = true,
  HasHeaderRecord = true,  
  HeaderValidated = null,
  MissingFieldFound = null,
  ShouldSkipRecord = record => string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.ToString()),
};

using (var reader = new StreamReader("Z:\\tmp\\test3.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
  csv.Read();
  csv.ReadHeader();
  var list = csv.GetRecords<GeoFeatures>().ToList();

  Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
}
```

**Try 2**

I have also tried a variation but only get id for each record.

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
  IgnoreBlankLines = true,
  HasHeaderRecord = true,  
  HeaderValidated = null,
  MissingFieldFound = null,
  ShouldSkipRecord = record => string.IsNullOrEmpty(record.ToString()),
};

using (var reader = new StreamReader("Z:\\tmp\\test3.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    var length = csv.HeaderRecord.Count();

    while (csv.Read())
    {
       var record = csv.GetRecord<dynamic>();

       // Do something with the record.
       Console.WriteLine(record.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your CSV as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. A CSV formatted as text will make it much easier for us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I did it to make it clear that it is an excel file..I will add the same as text too

Comment: It helps to see the CSV file because 1) That's what your code is actually reading, and 2) They are very easy to use as a [mcve].  ANd it seems like there's a problem with your CSV, namely that the values `Council Arterial` are not surrounded by quotes, nor is the inner space escaped, so they will count for two cells rather than one.  Could that be causing your problem?

Comment: Actually, your CSV isn't really a CSV at all.  Are you using space as a delimiter?

Comment: Hi, the shared link shows you the excel with json datatype column, from your excel, it does not contain any json data.